# Looking for Some Validation (or complete and utter destruction) of my Proposed Architecture

Tags: node.js, react-native, dialogflow-es

I am looking to create a chatbot mobile app to deploy to the Apple and Google Play stores.

I plan on using React Native for the front end, Node JS for the middle tier then DialogFlow for the backend.  I planned on having the middle tier mainly to hide the DialogFlow keys. I don't plan on doing much in Dialog Flow other than answering questions they ask.  I want to run it all on Google Cloud

First off, does that high level architecture make sense?

Secondly.. would Facebook and Google Authentication be the way to go for that.  And since it's a generic app, would I really need authorization?

Thirdly (is that a word).. what Google Platform services would you recommend me using (outside of DialogFlow) for running the react and node.

Thanks everyone.  I know this is a total newby question, but I'm just getting back into all of this.  It's literally been 20 years since I coded against the Servlet 1.0 API.  I have my Java Ring from one of the first JavaOne conferences to prove it.  lol.

Answer (score 0):

The architecture makes sense, I guess. There's certainly nothing wrong about it.

It does not sound like you need any client/server authentication, although if you wished, you could use Firebase Auth to provide the Google and Facebook authentication part.

If you want to stick to the Google Cloud environment, take a look at [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/), which provides a number of services that simplify your use of Google Cloud.

- [Firebase Hosting](https://firebase.google.com/products/hosting/) is an easy way to host and access static files and a website
- [Cloud Functions for Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/products/functions/) will give you a Node server that spins up and scales on demand and is a front for Google Cloud Functions
- [Firebase Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/products/auth/) provides a single way to manage users for a variety of auth providers

If you want to stick to Google Cloud itself, you may want to look into

- [Google Cloud Run](https://cloud.google.com/run/) which provides a way to scale stateless containers, kinda like Cloud Functions for any environment